# i have a problem with the serializer that registers a person

Tags: django-rest-framework

i extending a user model and creating a serializer that can register a user but i think i have a problem with the Register serializer

i have tried changing the input but i cant tell where the problem is

```python
class Register(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    register_as = models.CharField(max_length=20)


# register serializer
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model = Register
    fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'address', 'phone', 'register_as', 'password')
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only':True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(validated_data['username'], validated_data['email'], validated_data['password'])

        return user


#register API
class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):  
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):  

        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data) 
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()

        return Response({                                  
        'user': UserSerializer(user, 
        context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,  
        'token': AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1] 
        })
```

i expect it to return the fields in the user model plus the ones i added in the model

Comment: how's that `UserSerializer` being defined?

Comment: 'from django.contrib.auth.models import User'

Comment: by importing the User model i though i can just extend it using the OneToOneField